# Fresh Springboot project won't start Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot

I am trying out springboot, version `2.0.0.RELEASE` and I can't seem to be able to add the `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa` dependency

**pom.xml**

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.derby</groupId>
        <artifactId>derby</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

When starting the server, I can see this error in the logs

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/persistence/EntityManagerFactory
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.util.BeanDefinitionUtils.<clinit>(BeanDefinitionUtils.java:54) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.EntityManagerBeanDefinitionRegistrarPostProcessor.postProcessBeanFactory(EntityManagerBeanDefinitionRegistrarPostProcessor.java:54) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:284) ~[spring-context-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:179) ~[spring-context-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:693) ~[spring-context-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:531) ~[spring-context-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140) ~[spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:752) [spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:388) [spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:327) [spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1246) [spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1234) [spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at springbootstarter.CourseApiApp.main(CourseApiApp.java:10) [classes/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    ... 13 common frames omitted
```

Also, I can't import the `javax.persistence` package, so I think the dependency is not imported at all.

Could somebody tell me what I am doing wrong?

**EDIT**:
Here is the output of `mvn dependency:tree`

```
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:3.0.1:tree (default-cli) @ gs-accessing-data-jpa ---
[INFO] org.springframework:gs-accessing-data-jpa:jar:0.1.0
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:jar:2.0.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:2.0.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:jar:2.0.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:jar:2.0.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging:jar:2.0.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.2.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:1.2.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-to-slf4j:jar:2.10.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:jar:2.10.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:jar:1.7.25:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:jar:1.3.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.yaml:snakeyaml:jar:1.19:runtime
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-json:jar:2.0.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.9.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.9.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.9.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jdk8:jar:2.9.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:jar:2.9.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-parameter-names:jar:2.9.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat:jar:2.0.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:jar:8.5.28:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-el:jar:8.5.28:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-websocket:jar:8.5.28:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate.validator:hibernate-validator:jar:6.0.7.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- javax.validation:validation-api:jar:2.0.1.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.3.2.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.fasterxml:classmate:jar:1.3.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:5.0.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:5.0.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:5.0.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:5.0.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:5.0.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:5.0.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:jar:2.0.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-aop:jar:2.0.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:jar:1.8.13:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc:jar:2.0.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.zaxxer:HikariCP:jar:2.7.8:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:5.0.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:5.2.14.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.1-api:jar:1.0.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.22.0-GA:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- antlr:antlr:jar:2.7.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.jboss:jandex:jar:2.0.3.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- dom4j:dom4j:jar:1.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations:jar:5.0.1.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax.transaction:javax.transaction-api:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa:jar:2.0.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-commons:jar:2.0.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-orm:jar:5.0.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:5.0.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.25:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-aspects:jar:5.0.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.derby:derby:jar:10.14.1.0:runtime
[INFO] \- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:jar:2.0.0.RELEASE:test
[INFO]    +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test:jar:2.0.0.RELEASE:test
[INFO]    +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test-autoconfigure:jar:2.0.0.RELEASE:test
[INFO]    +- com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path:jar:2.4.0:test
[INFO]    |  \- net.minidev:json-smart:jar:2.3:test
[INFO]    |     \- net.minidev:accessors-smart:jar:1.2:test
[INFO]    |        \- org.ow2.asm:asm:jar:5.0.4:test
[INFO]    +- junit:junit:jar:4.12:test
[INFO]    +- org.assertj:assertj-core:jar:3.9.1:test
[INFO]    +- org.mockito:mockito-core:jar:2.15.0:test
[INFO]    |  +- net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy:jar:1.7.10:test
[INFO]    |  +- net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy-agent:jar:1.7.10:test
[INFO]    |  \- org.objenesis:objenesis:jar:2.6:test
[INFO]    +- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.3:test
[INFO]    +- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:jar:1.3:test
[INFO]    +- org.skyscreamer:jsonassert:jar:1.5.0:test
[INFO]    |  \- com.vaadin.external.google:android-json:jar:0.0.20131108.vaadin1:test
[INFO]    +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:5.0.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    |  \- org.springframework:spring-jcl:jar:5.0.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    +- org.springframework:spring-test:jar:5.0.4.RELEASE:test
[INFO]    \- org.xmlunit:xmlunit-core:jar:2.5.1:test
```

**EDIT**
Getting weirder
I can import `import javax.persistence.Id;`
but not  `import javax.persistence.Entity;`

**One more edit**
I can indeed access the source of `javax.persistence.Id` using my IDE, however, when I try to see the source of `javax.persistence.Entity`, it gives me this error. So I guess Davidxxx might be right and I am getting a corrupted jar from maven

```
java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid LOC header (bad signature)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.read(Native Method)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.access$1400(ZipFile.java:60)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipFileInputStream.read(ZipFile.java:734)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipFileInflaterInputStream.fill(ZipFile.java:434)
    at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(InflaterInputStream.java:158)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:246)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:286)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:345)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.util.Util.getInputStreamAsByteArray(Util.java:531)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.util.Util.getZipEntryByteContent(Util.java:697)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.nd.java.model.BinaryTypeFactory.rawReadTypeTestForExists(BinaryTypeFactory.java:165)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.nd.java.model.BinaryTypeFactory.rawReadType(BinaryTypeFactory.java:133)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.nd.java.model.BinaryTypeFactory.readType(BinaryTypeFactory.java:128)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.ClassFile.getJarBinaryTypeInfo(ClassFile.java:239)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.ClassFile.getBinaryTypeInfo(ClassFile.java:187)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.ClassFile.buildStructure(ClassFile.java:75)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.Openable.generateInfos(Openable.java:259)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaElement.openWhenClosed(JavaElement.java:583)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaElement.getElementInfo(JavaElement.java:320)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaElement.getElementInfo(JavaElement.java:306)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.Openable.getBuffer(Openable.java:285)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.AbstractClassFile.getBuffer(AbstractClassFile.java:212)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.AbstractClassFile.getSourceRange(AbstractClassFile.java:334)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.javaeditor.ClassFileEditor.probeInputForSource(ClassFileEditor.java:789)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.javaeditor.ClassFileEditor.doSetInput(ClassFileEditor.java:688)
    at org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.AbstractTextEditor$5.run(AbstractTextEditor.java:3154)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext.runInCurrentThread(ModalContext.java:437)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext.run(ModalContext.java:353)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow$14.run(WorkbenchWindow.java:2195)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow.run(WorkbenchWindow.java:2191)
    at org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.AbstractTextEditor.internalInit(AbstractTextEditor.java:3172)
    at org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.AbstractTextEditor.init(AbstractTextEditor.java:3197)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorReference.initialize(EditorReference.java:362)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.CompatibilityPart.create(CompatibilityPart.java:333)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:55)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.processAnnotated(InjectorImpl.java:990)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.processAnnotated(InjectorImpl.java:955)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.inject(InjectorImpl.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.internalMake(InjectorImpl.java:399)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.make(InjectorImpl.java:318)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.make(ContextInjectionFactory.java:162)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.createFromBundle(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:105)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.doCreate(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:74)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.create(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:56)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.ContributedPartRenderer.createWidget(ContributedPartRenderer.java:129)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createWidget(PartRenderingEngine.java:992)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:661)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:767)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.access$0(PartRenderingEngine.java:738)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$2.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:732)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:716)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl$1.handleEvent(PartServiceImpl.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.internal.events.UIEventHandler$1.run(UIEventHandler.java:40)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.syncExec(Synchronizer.java:233)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.UISynchronizer.syncExec(UISynchronizer.java:144)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.syncExec(Display.java:5535)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application$1.syncExec(E4Application.java:212)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.internal.events.UIEventHandler.handleEvent(UIEventHandler.java:36)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerWrapper.handleEvent(EventHandlerWrapper.java:201)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerTracker.dispatchEvent(EventHandlerTracker.java:197)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerTracker.dispatchEvent(EventHandlerTracker.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventAdminImpl.dispatchEvent(EventAdminImpl.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventAdminImpl.sendEvent(EventAdminImpl.java:78)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventComponent.sendEvent(EventComponent.java:39)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.internal.events.EventBroker.send(EventBroker.java:52)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.UIEventPublisher.notifyChanged(UIEventPublisher.java:60)
    at org.eclipse.emf.common.notify.impl.BasicNotifierImpl.eNotify(BasicNotifierImpl.java:374)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.model.application.ui.impl.ElementContainerImpl.setSelectedElement(ElementContainerImpl.java:173)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ModelServiceImpl.showElementInWindow(ModelServiceImpl.java:620)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ModelServiceImpl.bringToTop(ModelServiceImpl.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.delegateBringToTop(PartServiceImpl.java:769)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.bringToTop(PartServiceImpl.java:401)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.showPart(PartServiceImpl.java:1188)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.busyOpenEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:3261)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.access$25(WorkbenchPage.java:3176)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage$10.run(WorkbenchPage.java:3158)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:3153)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:3117)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:3107)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.javaeditor.EditorUtility.openInEditor(EditorUtility.java:373)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.javaeditor.EditorUtility.openInEditor(EditorUtility.java:179)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.ui.actions.OpenAction.run(OpenAction.java:279)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.ui.actions.OpenAction.run(OpenAction.java:244)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.ui.actions.SelectionDispatchAction.dispatchRun(SelectionDispatchAction.java:271)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.ui.actions.SelectionDispatchAction.run(SelectionDispatchAction.java:249)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.packageview.PackageExplorerActionGroup.handleOpen(PackageExplorerActionGroup.java:379)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.packageview.PackageExplorerPart$4.open(PackageExplorerPart.java:541)
    at org.eclipse.ui.OpenAndLinkWithEditorHelper$InternalListener.open(OpenAndLinkWithEditorHelper.java:46)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer$2.run(StructuredViewer.java:851)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.JFaceUtil.lambda$0(JFaceUtil.java:44)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.SafeRunnable.run(SafeRunnable.java:173)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.fireOpen(StructuredViewer.java:848)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.handleOpen(StructuredViewer.java:1163)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy.fireOpenEvent(OpenStrategy.java:273)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy.access$2(OpenStrategy.java:268)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy$1.handleEvent(OpenStrategy.java:308)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:5348)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1348)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4602)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:4183)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$5.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1150)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:336)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1039)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:153)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.lambda$3(Workbench.java:680)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:336)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:594)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:151)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:388)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:243)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:653)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:590)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1499)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1472)
```

**Now sorted**
It was a corrupted jar in my maven repo, removing the `~/.m2` folder worked.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In maven a managed dependency by the parent pom is not de facto included in the current pom.
It is a dependency that you include on demand by declaring it in the `dependencies` section of the current pom.
Make a dependency managed by a parent pom allows to set the dependency version in the definition of this parent pom. That define them a single time. Which is a good thing.

This message is simply an information message :

> The managed version is 2.0.0.RELEASE The artifact is managed in
>   org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:2.0.0.RELEASE

And you need to declare the dependency in this way if you want to pull this dependency in your current project :

```
<dependencies>
    ...
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    ...
</dependencies>
```

Your Maven dependencies are probably broken in your local repository. Try to remove them from your local Maven repository and after try again to execute `mvn spring-boot:run`.
To clear the dependencies you could execute `mvn dependency:purge-local-repository` from your project.

If that does not work, you can also try to completely remove the local repository folder. It is at this location by default:

> Unix/Mac OS X: `~/.m2`
>
> Windows: `C:\Documents and Settings\{your-username}\.m2`

Comment: ok, that clears a lot of things up in my mind, but when I include it in the pom.xml, I get the `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory` error, and I can't import the `javax.persistence` package in my code, so it looks like it does not include it. I cleaned and rebuilt the whole thing many times

Comment: Your dependencies are probably broken. Clear them from your local Maven repository and start it again. Try to run  `mvn dependency:purge-local-repository`

Comment: Tried purge, but sadly I still have the same issue, whether I run it from the command line of with Eclipse (Spring Tools Suite)

Comment: I added an edit, importing the `javax.persistence` dependency works, just not `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa`

Comment: I still bet you have an inconsistency dependency broken (probably a pom.xml) . mvn `dependency:tree` should show that. Try and edit your answer with the output.

Comment: I added the output of `mvn tree`, `data-jpa` seems to be there. I can see `org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.1-api:jar`, shouldn't there be the base JPA package? `javax.persistence`

Comment: Hi, finally worked it out, and you were right, the repo was corrupted, see my latest edit. I completely deleted it `rm -rf ~/.m2` and rebuilt the project, now it works. I'll add it to your answer and accept it. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Bentaye You are very welcome. And thanks for the feedback about `mvn dependency:purge-local-repository` that didn't produce the expected result :-)

Comment: I can confirm that after I delete the maven repo using the command `rm -rf ~/.m2`, it all works out.